# Calling Function with ListBoxes

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a function take two list boxes, take one value from one list box and add that value to another. I placed the function in my Module. Here is the 
code.

Here is the function:

```
Function addtolist(selectionlist As ListBox, listselected As ListBox)

For i = 0 To selectionlist.ListCount - 1
    If selectionlist.selected(i) = True Then
        listselected.AddItem selectionlist.List(i)

    End If

Next i

For i = selectionlist.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If selectionlist.selected(i) = True Then
        selectionlist.RemoveItem i

    End If

Next i
End Function
```

In the private sub, a button click, I am doing the following:

```
Call addtolist(selectionlist, listselected)
```

I keep getting Run Time Error '13' Type mismatch.

Please help!

Comment: Which line triggers the error?

Comment: The Call addtolist(selectionlist, list selected) line is highlighted.  I just needed to add MSForms to the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the code and the error you *expose*, I'd say you have to change the declaration of your function arguments type to `MSForms.ListBox`:

```
Function addtolist(selectionlist As MSForms.ListBox, listselected As MSForms.ListBox)
```

Comment: This solved the issue. Thinking back, I saw this in one example online, but it didn't stick out and I didn't try it. Thank you! By the way, why do I need to declare MSForms? What makes me have to do that?

Comment: You are welcome. These links ([link1](http://wellsr.com/vba/2016/excel/complete-guide-to-excel-vba-form-control-listboxes/), [link2](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2519bdf4-e516-4c02-80f7-b5364e6ee0e6/quirk-in-passing-a-combobox-and-listbox-as-a-parameter?forum=exceldev))  could help you in understandng the differences. Finally since I solved your question you may want to mark answer as accepted. thank you!